# CONNECT BY and START WITH clauses in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy, connect-by

I want hierarchical data for the test data given below. For user 'jones' it should fetch the below records. I am having problem with CONNECT BY and START WITH clauses.
I also think there is some JOIN problem between  menu_items AND  role_menu_items tables.

for user and their corresponding roles i need to fecth below data

```
select  mi.id,  mi.NAME,mi.MEN_ID,mi.ICON,mi.ACTION--,r.NAME 
from
menu_items mi,
role_menu_items rmi,
roles r,
USERS U,
USER_ROLES UR
where
mi.ID=rmi.MIT_ID and
rmi.ROL_ID=r.id and
r.id=UR.ROLE_ID and
U.ID=UR.USER_ID and
U.NAME='jones'
start with mi.men_id is null
connect by   prior  mi.ID=mi.men_id
```

Output

```
1   Menu1           Menu1       /images/home.gif
3   Help            Help    
4   page1   a   1   page1   1   /images/email.gif
7   about   d   1   about   3
```

---

```
Insert into MENU_ITEMS (ID,NAME,SHORTCUT,DISPLAY_SEQUENCE,ACTION,MEN_ID,ICON) 
  values (1,'Menu1',null,null,'Menu1',null,'/images/home.gif');

Insert into MENU_ITEMS (ID,NAME,SHORTCUT,DISPLAY_SEQUENCE,ACTION,MEN_ID,ICON) 
  values (2,'Menu2',null,null,'Menu2',null,null);

Insert into MENU_ITEMS (ID,NAME,SHORTCUT,DISPLAY_SEQUENCE,ACTION,MEN_ID,ICON) 
  values (3,'Help',null,null,'Help',null,null);

Insert into MENU_ITEMS (ID,NAME,SHORTCUT,DISPLAY_SEQUENCE,ACTION,MEN_ID,ICON) 
  values (4,'page1','a',1,'page1',1,'/images/email.gif');

Insert into MENU_ITEMS (ID,NAME,SHORTCUT,DISPLAY_SEQUENCE,ACTION,MEN_ID,ICON) 
  values (5,'page2','b',2,'page2',1,null);

Insert into MENU_ITEMS (ID,NAME,SHORTCUT,DISPLAY_SEQUENCE,ACTION,MEN_ID,ICON) 
  values (6,'page3','c',1,'page3',2,'/images/photo.gif');

Insert into MENU_ITEMS (ID,NAME,SHORTCUT,DISPLAY_SEQUENCE,ACTION,MEN_ID,ICON) 
  values (7,'about','d',1,'about',3,null);

insert into ROLES (ID, NAME)
values (1, 'administrator');

insert into ROLES (ID, NAME)
values (2, 'user');

Insert into ROLE_MENU_ITEMS (ROL_ID,MIT_ID) values (1,4);
Insert into ROLE_MENU_ITEMS (ROL_ID,MIT_ID) values (1,5);
Insert into ROLE_MENU_ITEMS (ROL_ID,MIT_ID) values (1,6);
Insert into ROLE_MENU_ITEMS (ROL_ID,MIT_ID) values (1,7);
Insert into ROLE_MENU_ITEMS (ROL_ID,MIT_ID) values (2,4);
Insert into ROLE_MENU_ITEMS (ROL_ID,MIT_ID) values (2,7);

Insert into USER_ROLES (USER_ID,ROLE_ID) values (2,2);
Insert into USER_ROLES (USER_ID,ROLE_ID) values (1,1);
Insert into USER_ROLES (USER_ID,ROLE_ID) values (3,2);

Insert into USERS (ID,NAME,PASSWORD) values (2,'scott','scott');
Insert into USERS (ID,NAME,PASSWORD) values (1,'john','john');
Insert into USERS (ID,NAME,PASSWORD) values (3,'jones','jones');
```

Comment: +1 for supplying a complete set of test data

Comment: I mentioned the output in the original question itself.

Comment: with the above query am getting only this output.4   page1   a   1   page1   1   /images/email.gif 7   about   d   1   about   3

Comment: for `administrator` role you have only 4,5,6,7 menu items. no `1,'Menu1'` or `3,'Help'`

Comment: as you said for administrator role you have only 4,5,6,7 menu items i.e.page1,page2,page3 and aboutsub menu items and also it should display their corresponding parent items i.e.Menu1,Menu2 and Help.

Comment: for 'user' role it should fetch only page1 and about sub menu items and also their corresponding menus i.e.Menu1 and Help.

Comment: If they should be displayed, then add them to ROLE_MENU_ITEMS.

Comment: as you said if i add MENU_ITEMS related id's in ROLE_MENU_ITEMS table then it will fetch the records.

Comment: but without adding those records in ROLE_MENU_ITEMS  can't we fetch the parent-parent records from MENU_ITEMS table itself.

Comment: if we do like this without using CONNECT BY PRIOR CLAUSE and START WITH clauses we can retreive the records.but as i said without adding MENU related id's in  ROLE_MENU_ITEMS how can we these records using CONNECT BY PRIOR CLAUSE

Comment: apart from that ROLE_MENU_ITEMS table exists only for adding sub-menu items not for adding menu items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bad scheme, but it is possible

**1.** select all menu_id for user role

---

```
select RMI.MIT_ID
from ROLE_MENU_ITEMS RMI
   , ROLES R
   , USERS U
   , USER_ROLES UR
where RMI.ROL_ID = R.ID
  and R.ID = UR.ROLE_ID
  and U.ID = UR.USER_ID
  and U.NAME = 'jones'
```

**2.** reverse hierarhy query

---

```
select MI.*
     , max(LEVEL) over () + 1 - level as rev_level
     , lpad(' ', (max(LEVEL) over () + 1 - LEVEL) * 3, ' ') || MI.NAME as LEVEL_NAME
     , rownum RN
from MENU_ITEMS MI
connect by prior MEN_ID = ID
start with ID IN (select RMI.MIT_ID
                  from ROLE_MENU_ITEMS RMI
                     , ROLES R
                     , USERS U
                     , USER_ROLES UR
                  where RMI.ROL_ID = R.ID
                    and R.ID = UR.ROLE_ID
                    and U.ID = UR.USER_ID
                    and U.NAME = 'jones')
```

**3.** reverse (reverse hierarhy query)

---

```
select ID
     , NAME
     , SHORTCUT
     , DISPLAY_SEQUENCE
     , ACTION
     , MEN_ID
     , ICON
     , LEVEL_NAME
from 
(
    select MI.*
         , max(LEVEL) over () + 1 - level as rev_level
         , lpad(' ', (max(LEVEL) over () + 1 - LEVEL) * 3, ' ') || MI.NAME as LEVEL_NAME
         , rownum RN
    from MENU_ITEMS MI
    connect by prior MEN_ID = ID
    start with ID IN (select RMI.MIT_ID
                      from ROLE_MENU_ITEMS RMI
                         , ROLES R
                         , USERS U
                         , USER_ROLES UR
                      where RMI.ROL_ID = R.ID
                        and R.ID = UR.ROLE_ID
                        and U.ID = UR.USER_ID
                        and U.NAME = 'jones')
)
group by ID --distinct with order
       , name
       , SHORTCUT
       , DISPLAY_SEQUENCE
       , ACTION
       , MEN_ID
       , ICON
       , LEVEL_NAME
order by min(-RN)
```

possible to keep the sort of root items by ID, using a subquery

```
select ID
     , NAME
     , SHORTCUT
     , DISPLAY_SEQUENCE
     , ACTION
     , MEN_ID
     , ICON
     , LEVEL_NAME
from 
(
    select ID
         , NAME
         , SHORTCUT
         , DISPLAY_SEQUENCE
         , ACTION
         , MEN_ID
         , ICON
         , MAX(LVL) OVER () + 1 - LVL
         , rpad(' ', (max(LVL) over () + 1 - LVL) * 3, ' ') || NAME as LEVEL_NAME
         , RN
    from (
        select MI.*
             , rownum RN
             , level LVL
        from MENU_ITEMS MI
        connect by prior MEN_ID = ID
        start with ID IN (select RMI.MIT_ID
                          from ROLE_MENU_ITEMS RMI
                             , ROLES R
                             , USERS U
                             , USER_ROLES UR
                          where RMI.ROL_ID = R.ID
                            and R.ID = UR.ROLE_ID
                            and U.ID = UR.USER_ID
                            and U.NAME = 'jones')
        order siblings by -ID
    )
)
group by ID --distinct with order
       , name
       , SHORTCUT
       , DISPLAY_SEQUENCE
       , ACTION
       , MEN_ID
       , ICON
       , LEVEL_NAME
order by min(-RN)
```

Comment: turbanoff, Please see my comments at the end of your last post.i added two more records('page4',page5') under 'page1' sub menu in MENU_ITEMS and ROLE_MENU_ITEMS respectively but query fetching duplicate records.